# "git reset --hard" takes time in case of copied folder

Tags: git

When any changes in worktree are nothing, `git reset --hard` is finished soon.
However, it takes time if I copy the workspace into an other folder.

For example,

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts -b main
$ cd cts
$ git reset --hard  # CaseA

$ cd ..
$ cp -a cts cts2
$ cd cts2
$ git reset --hard  # CaseB
```

"CaseA" is finished soon. (about 80 msec)
"CaseB" takes time. (about 6000 msec)
As you can see, I simply executed `copy`.
How can I speed up "CaseB" ?

I'll summarize here what I found out about "CaseB".

- The timestamp of all files in worktree was updated. (about 27,000 files)
- The contents of all files in worktree were not changed. (same contents)
- The content of HEAD in .git/ was not changed, but timestamp was updated.
- The content of index in .git/ was changed.

I'd like to finish "CaseB" soon same as "CaseA".
How can I speed up "CaseB" ?

[Note]
I have listed steps that are easier to reproduce, but in reality, I am facing this problem when I have downloaded the workspace from a file server.

Comment: Why `copy` instead of `git clone` again locally?

Comment: Sorry, I have added lack information.

Comment: I think you would see a similar delay if you simply ran `git status`. git relies on its index to perform many actions quickly, if it deems that the files have changed on disk it will have to re-scan them entirely though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to make a copy of a repository and then expect the copy to have a suitably ready `.git/index` file in practically zero time. The way in which Git works, this is impossible.

The `.git/index` file records file meta data like timestamps, file size, and inode numbers. The purpose of this information is that Git can identify *unchanged* files without having to look at the content of the files themselves. This makes the first `git reset --hard` in the original repository so fast: no changed metadata means that no files have been changed, so none of them needs to be re-written.

By making a copy of the working tree including the repository, all files receive new timestamps, new inode numbers, or both. This basically "invalidates" the cached metadata in the copied `.git/index` file. Git has to assume pessimistically that the files have been modified. It has to inspect all file contents to verify if there was indeed no change. Or, in the case of `git reset --hard`, has to pull the files out of the repository and write them to the working tree. That takes the time that you observe.

Comment: Thanks, I understood. I have found some related questions, so I share them.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075528/what-algorithm-does-git-use-to-detect-changes-on-your-working-tree and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778862/how-does-git-detect-that-a-file-has-been-modified

Answer (score 1):

use `rsync` instead of `cp`

```
rsync -a --no-time <source> <dest>
```

then do git reset

[rsync vs cp command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339287/copy-or-rsync-command)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with `rsync -a --noatime <source> <dest>`, but, unfortunately the result was same.

Comment: in that case, maybe you can download the file in .tar.gz format and then untar/unzip them and do git reset --hard , instead of using git clone

Comment: Yes. More detail, the workspace is stored with `.tar`.