# Why does git run a refresh of the index when I copy and paste a repo

Tags: git

I have a repo checked out on Windows 11. When I copy and paste that repo on the file system, and then run a 'git status' in the new copied repo, it runs a 'refreshing index' command that takes a couple minutes to complete. Why is this?

Comment: What sort of filesystem is this?

Comment: Windows 11 NTFS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["git reset --hard" takes time in case of copied folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77435024/git-reset-hard-takes-time-in-case-of-copied-folder)

Answer (score 2):

Git stores information in the index, including the file size, the device and inode numbers, and the file creation time.  This information allows it to avoid re-reading unchanged files; conversely, if the information does change, then Git knows the file has been changed and it must re-read it.

When you copy a repository, the device and inode numbers and the file creation time are changed, so Git needs to re-read the file in the working tree to see what's modified.  There's really not a good way to avoid this; while there are some options you can use, you risk failing to detect real changes, especially since yours is a case Git intends to detect.

If your goal is just to check out a different branch, try using `git worktree` to create another worktree with the same `.git` directory.  In addition to saving disk space, this allows you to create and destroy as many worktrees as you like, provided that you never have the same branch checked out more than once.